# this.setTimeout() is not a function React native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to create a simple stopwatch timer in React Native and I've created a new component called Chrono to handle the clock data(hours, minutes, etc.)

I'm triggering the clock count up on a button press in the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Chrono from './app/Chrono.js';

export default class morphX extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      randomCounter: 0
    }
    this.chrono = null
  }

  onItemPressed = () => {
    this.chrono.startTimer()
  }

  updateRandomCounter = () => {
    this.setState({
      randomCounter: this.state.randomCounter + 1
    })
  }

  clearCounter = () => {
    this.setState({ 
      randomCounter: 0
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainWrapper}>
        <View style={styles.upperWrapper}>
          <Chrono ref = { r => this.chrono = r} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bottomWrapper}>
          <View style={styles.initialButtons}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.touchableButton}
              text="Let's Start!"
              onPress={() => this.onItemPressed()}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonTexts}>
                Count Up!
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.touchableButton}
              title="RESET!"
              onPress={() => this.clearCounter()}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonTexts}>
                Reset!
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('morphX', () => morphX);
```

and the `startTimer` is implemented in the `Chrono.js` component here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';

class Chrono extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            hours: 0,
            minutes: 0,
            seconds: 0
        }
    }

    // Chronometer start function
    startTimer = () => {
        console.log(this)
        this.setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('HeY!')
            this.setState({
                seconds: 1
            })  
        }, 1000);
    }

    // Chronometer pause function 
    pauseTimer = () => {

    }

    // Chronometer reset function 
    resetTimer = () => {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.clockWrapper}>
                <Text style={styles.hourWrapper}>
                    {this.state.hours}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.colonWrapper}>
                    :
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.minuteWrapper}>
                    {this.state.minutes}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.colonWrapper}>
                    :
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.secondsWrapper}>
                    {this.state.seconds}
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Chrono
```

I'm facing the error

> `this.setTimeout` is not a function

on the line where I'm calling the `setTimeout` for some reason. Why?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder React-Native has its own implementation of Timers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder react-native usually comes with all the capabilities all together. 99% of the topics talked in docs already included, this is one of that isn't. Its pretty understandable for a new user to expect it already included.

Comment: @bennygenel: I'm shocked to see that the mixin puts it on the component itself. Following the link you provide below explains why; without that context, it seems like massive smell. And that explains the OP's question, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TimerMixin** is not included with the default react-native. You have to install it yourself and then you can use `this.setTimeout`. Check [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html#timermixin) for detailed information.

> This library does not ship with React Native - in order to use it on
>   your project, you will need to install it with
>   `npm i react-timer-mixin --save`
>   from your project directory.

---

> Keep in mind that if you use ES6 classes for your React components
>   [there is no built-in API for mixins](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#mixins). To use TimerMixin with ES6
>   classes, we recommend [react-mixin](https://github.com/brigand/react-mixin).

Comment: (november 2017). I hope everyone using ES6. And (https://github.com/brigand/react-mixin) react-mixin is said to be deprecated.
Is this the right way to solve the issue ?

Comment: @LouisLecocq I don't think it is still a valid solution.

Comment: Ok. i thought the answer was posted in September 2017.
I'll try to post a new  one then

Comment: @LouisLecocq it would be nice to have a better answer if you have any. OP can change the answer ans I can delete mine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513549/timers-in-react-native-this-settimeout
feel free to add any details in edit mode ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm used `setTimeout()` without including `react-timer-mixin`, and its working fine in my application.

```
componentDidMount() {

    const a = setTimeout(() => {

      // do some stuff here

    }, 100);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() is global and actually window.setTimeout() in a browser, in React Native window is implied for global functions that use it. so this.setTimeout() should actually be just setTimeout().

Additionally see [setTimeout in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504322/settimeout-in-react-native) that the callback function inside the setTimeout() changes the scope of "this"