# Timers in React Native (this.setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, react-native, timer

I'm trying to set up a TimeOut function in my component.
To my understanding, just using setTimeout as you would for the web isn't a proper answer. It would cause timing and leak memory issue.

I've read there is an existing [Timers API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html) in react-native.

However, it is not compliant with ES6, i quote :

> Keep in mind that if you use ES6 classes for your React components there is no built-in API for mixins. To use TimerMixin with ES6 classes, we recommend react-mixin.

And on [react-mixin](https://github.com/brigand/react-mixin), we find this message :

> Note: mixins are basically dead. Only use this as a migration path for legacy code. Prefer High Order Components.

So my final question is : **How do we properly use timers (setTimeOut), with react-native, in 2017 ?**

Comment: Hmm. Used `setTimeOut` a lot. Never faced any issue yet.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Settimeout and setInterval still work in react-native. BUT you have to use it in the right way:

Here is one of many ways to implement a timeout in React that I'm usually used:

```
export default class Loading extends Component {
  state = {
    timer: null,
    counter: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
    this.setState({timer});
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.state.timer);
  }

  tick =() => {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Loading{"...".substr(0, this.state.counter % 3 + 1)}</div>
  }
}
```

With this approach you don't have to worry about memory leak anymore. Just simple and straight forward.

There is an excellent article talking about this; you can refer to it here: https://medium.com/@machadogj/timers-in-react-with-redux-apps-9a5a722162e8

Comment: I might declare `tick()` as `tick = () =>` in order to preserve the scope of the React Component.

Comment: change the code from `this.tick` to `this.tick.bind(this)`

Comment: Remove the `this.` from `this.clearInterval(this.state.time)`, otherwise it will throw an error for me!

Answer (score 14):

For the sake of also adding what it would look like with functional component and hooks.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'

const Component = props => {

    useEffect(() => {
        let timer = setInterval(() => console.log('fire!'), 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(timer)
    }, [])

    return <Text>Example of using setInterval with hooks</Text>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take **refrence** from @chiquyet ,
**Thank you @chiquyet**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47549754/11754047

```
this.clearInterval(this.state.timer);
```

Will throw error in **react native**

**Description**

Simple timer in react native with 5 secounds, along with **validation** and **alert**

I try in, () =>
**"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",**

Snack Expo Link () => https://snack.expo.io/PuYxRmueW

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, Button, SafeAreaView, TextInput } from 'react-native'

export default class Timer extends React.Component {

    state = {
        timer: null,
        counter: 5,
    };

    startTimer = () => {

        let timer = setInterval(this.manageTimer, 1000);
        this.setState({ timer });

    }

    manageTimer = () => {

        var states = this.state

        if (states.counter === 0) {
            alert('Times Up !\nTimer  is reset')
            clearInterval(this.state.timer)
            this.setState({
                counter: 5
            })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                counter: this.state.counter - 1
            });

        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.state.timer);
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView>


                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{this.state.counter}</Text>

                <View>
                    <Button
                        title='START TIMER'
                        onPress={() => this.startTimer()}
                    />
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score -4):

Timer is not a part of 'react-native' package

- cd /path_to_your_project
- install react-timer-mixin package
- add Timer in .js file
- setup timer

  ```
  npm i react-timer-mixin --save (from console)

  import TimerMixin from 'react-timer-mixin';
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      //DO SOMETHING
  }, 5);
  ```

Comment: Looks pretty outdated imo

Comment: @LouisLecocq, could you explain why?

Comment: @AlexV See above accepted answer.  `react-timer-mixin` not needed.  You can use `setInterval` in reaect-native out of the box.