# JavaScript setTimeout() function responses unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, react-native, settimeout

I am trying to build a system where a user can call another user. The call is received by a socket connection. When the socket event is received, a function `handleEmergencyCall` is called. If the user does not accept the call within 15 seconds, the call is forwarded to the next active user. I've implemented the functionality using `setTimeout`
The overall  `handleEmergencyCall` looks like :

```
// emergency call
  const handleEmergencyCall = (opId) => {
    setOperationStatusHandler("calling");
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSound(null);
      console.log(operationStatus); //calling
      if (operationStatus == "calling") {
        removeOperationStatusHandler();
        console.log("time out");
        updateEmergencyCallStatus({ reason: "time out", operationId: opId });
      }
    }, 1000 * 15);
  };
```

The `setOperationStatusHandler` is in AuthContext which looks like:

```
  const setOperationStatusHandler = async (status) => {
    setOperationStatus(status);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("operationStatus", status);
  };

  const removeOperationStatusHandler = async () => {
    setOperationStatus(null);
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem("operationStatus");
  };
```

everything is working perfectly. But what I noticed that, if I don't log the `operationStatus` before the `if (operationStatus == "calling")` then the if condition does not work.
Can anyone explain why this wired thing is happening here?

Comment: Where do you set this `operationStatus`?

Comment: can you add the method setOperationStatusHandler here?

Comment: thanks for your interest here. I've edited the post and add the `setOperationStatusHandle` there.

Comment: What is `setOperationStatus`? Where is `operationStauts` defined? What's its initial value?

Comment: Are you sure about this behavior with and without ```console.log```? I have encountered similar issue before and it only seems like that ```console.log``` had any effect but in reality it was random behavior.

Comment: Related question: [Timers in React Native (this.setTimeout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513549/timers-in-react-native-this-settimeout/47549754#47549754)

Comment: Store the latest value of `operationStatus` in a `ref` as well. Then refer to the `ref` within your `setTimeout` instead of using state value

Comment: @AmitKumar, it is actually random behavior. I realize it now.

Comment: @derpirscher ` const [operationStatus, setOperationStatus] = useState(null);` which is defined in a context. When there is call, I change the value using the `setOperationStatusHandler`.

Comment: try to narrow down the issue so that someone can help. your current logic looks good.