# Javascript setTimeout Immediately runs in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, settimeout

My problem is that setTimeout runs ‍`about 5 seconds` earlier.
For example, when I set it to `5 seconds`, it runs immediately, but when I am on the `15 seconds`, it will run for about `10 seconds` later.

I even surveyed this question: [setTimeout in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504322/settimeout-in-react-native), but I still could not solve the problem

```
changeNotify() {
    let that = this;
    console.log("before");
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("After");
        that.setState({notifyModal: false})
    }, 5000);
}
```

And in render

```
<Button
   title='change'
   onPress={() => this.setState({notifyModal: true},()=>this.changeNotify())}
/>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The code above was correct.

There was a problem, because I was in the `debug mode` and my device's time don't matches that of my computer!

This happened to me and took an unfortunately long while to debug

Comment: if this solves the problem select it as the chosen answer. Yes, even when you solved it yourself.

Comment: I can confirm my answer after two days. This law is stackoverflow supposedly

Comment: I cannot imagine that this solution worked perfectly ^^,

Comment: WTf man! wasted my 2hrs on this. Thanks for the solution man

Comment: SAVE THE DAY MAN REALLY GENIUS