# How can I move from splash screen to login screen after some seconds in react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I am a beginner in react native and very confused about navigation between two screens after x second delay.

How can I move from splash screen to login screen after some seconds in react native?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504322/settimeout-in-react-native will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

this is how iv'e achieved that by having a splashscreen as inital route in stackNavigator and then in componentDidMount after 3 secs im navigating to LoginScreen.

```
 {
      initialRouteName: "SplashScreen"

 }
```

this is inside the stack navigator.

and inside the componentDidMount of the splashScreen class im doing this

```
componentDidMount(){
window.setTimeout(async () => {
      const token = await isSignedIn();
      this.props.navigation.navigate(token ? 'HomeScreen' : 'OnBoardingScreen');
    }, 3000);
}
```

so what im doing is, im checking if token is stored in asyncStorage by the `isSignedIn()`. and if token is present then im navigating to `HomeScreen or LoginScreen` respectively after 3 secs.(3000 denotes in ms)

Feel free for doubts.

UPDATE:

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { isSignedIn } from '../../services/auth';
import Animation from "lottie-react-native";
import styles from './SplashScreenStyle';

```
export default class SplashScreen extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    StatusBar.setHidden(true);
    this._playAnimation();
    window.setTimeout(async () => {
      const token = await isSignedIn();
      this.props.navigation.navigate(token ? 'HomeScreen' : 'OnBoardingScreen');
    }, 2120);
  }

  state = {
    animation: null,
  };

  _playAnimation = () => {
    if (!this.state.animation) {
      this._loadAnimationAsync();
    } else {
      this.animation.play();
    }
  };

  _loadAnimationAsync = async () => {
    let result = await fetch(
      "https://assets1.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_vi3n1R.json"
    )
      .then(data => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    this.setState({ animation: result }, this._playAnimation);
  };

  render() {


    return (
      <View style={styles.animationContainer}>
        {this.state.animation && (
          <Animation
            ref={animation => {
              this.animation = animation;
            }}
            style={{ width: 200, height: 200, backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
            source={this.state.animation}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your splash screen?