# how can i change background after 1 second in react native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

What I'm trying to do is that the background color inside the box stays colored for 0.5 seconds and then disappears. like When you click the YouTube comment alarm, the background color inside the box disappears.

when first rendering

there is background color
[image]

0.5 second later background color disappear like this

[image]

this is my code

```
    const Container = styled.View`
    border-bottom-color: lightblue;
    `;
    const CommentContainer = styled.View`
    `;

    const SecondCommentCon = styled.View`
    `;

    const UnserName = styled.Text`
    `;
    const Label = styled.Text`
    `;

    const TodoList = ({}) => {

      return (

      <Container>
      <CommentContainer>
      <SecondCommentCon>
      <UnserName>{yes?.[0]?.User?.nickname}</UnserName>
      <Label>{yes?.[0]?.content}</Label>
      </SecondCommentCon>
      </CommentContainer>
      </Container>

      )
```

what code should i add??

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504322/settimeout-in-react-native

Comment: Have you tried out the answer I posted? Consider giving some feedback, thank you!

Comment: @axtck sorry for late feedback in works! thank you!!!!

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout()` to change the background color of the element by its `className` after a specified time.

First, define a class in a CSS file with the background color you want the element to be on mount

```css
.bg-onmount {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

Make sure you import this file (`import "./App.css"` for example).

Then you declare a state variable with an initial value of the class name you defined

```js
// a state variable for the background class
const [backgroundClass, setBackgroundClass] = useState("bg-onmount");
```

This state value will be bound to the `className` property of the element later on.

In your `useEffect()` you can set the timer with the amount of time you would want it to be that color, in your case this would be 500ms. After that time, the state value will be updated to the new `className` which we set to `""`, so the background color disappears and the component re-renders.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // set a timer
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setBackgroundClass(""); // set class to none
  }, 500);

  // don't forget to clear in cleanup
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  };
}, []);
```

Don't forget to call `clearTimeout()` in your cleanup function, this will stop the timer when the component unmounts.

This is how you would bind this value to your element

```html
return (
  <div className={backgroundClass}>
    <p>Some text here</p>
  </div>
);
```

Try it out in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-gould-fbt7f?file=/src/App.js)