# setTimeout function does not display HTML after function ends

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a timeout function for 3 seconds and after that time it is supposed to render the HTML. I'm following the official documentation to do this and the code is like on the documentation. Anyone has had a similar issue?

```js
render() {
return (
<div>
    {this.state.activePage === 'Home' ? setTimeout(function () {
        <p>Hello World</p>
    }, 3000) : null}
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: Don't do this in the render. Instead use a `useEffect`, or put it in the constructor, and change state.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you are seeing this in the documentation?  Was was not under the impression you could execute asynchronous code inside of JSX in this manner....

Comment: [This approach uses react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504322/settimeout-in-react-native), but it's pretty much the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You should not write code like that in react. The `setTimeout` returns:

> The returned timeoutID is a positive integer value which identifies
> the timer created by the call to setTimeout(). T

and not the JSX which you returned from callback. But even if it did *asynchronously* return the JSX which you return from callback, you won't see the *new* content on the screen. To change UI in react you must change a state variable using `setState` which will cause a re render. Also render is not the place to call `setState`. You can call `setState` in `useEffect` for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to return a value from the function passed to setTimeout.

Here are two options you could try

1. Create a state field to store the message you want to display and update the state from inside of the setTimeout. Also such an update cannot be done inside of the return. You would want to move this logic to a component mount function.
2. Here is a more vanilla JS approach to this issue using promise objects
   [Get return value from setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928846/get-return-value-from-settimeout)

Also could you provide the document you are referring to for this code, so we can have a deeper dive onto the issue?